# Consultar la base de datos Firebase

Tags: ionic, firebase, sync-framework

Resulta que me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en ionic y con consulta a firebase, mi aplicación tiene asociada un logueo el cual funciona perfectamente pero me presenta un problema y es que no me hace la consulta de datos en la firebase.

Me hago explicar, cuando ingreso mi usuario correo la aplicación ingresa perfectamente, pero tengo una tab que me muestra diferente info que se sube a firebase, esa es la consulta que no me esta haciendo.

Código correspondiente al index creo que tengo las librerías y todo lo necesario para el funcionamiento de la app:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','starter.services',])

 .run(function ($ionicPlatform, FirebaseDB,$rootScope, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
       var ref = new Firebase('aqui va el enlace de mi firebase')

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });

    FirebaseDB.initialize();


    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
      function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {


        if (error === "NO USER") {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("go to login state");
          $state.go('login', {});
        }
      });

  })
```

correspondiente al app.js es aquí donde surge el problema y es que mientras no agregue 'firebase' la app funciona pero sin la consulta de datos, cuando agrego 'firebase' se queda la pantalla en blanco. O sea, cuando

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','starter.services',´firebase'])
```

queda de ese modo se me bloquea la app.

Comment: el error que me arroja es GET http://192.168.43.172:8100/lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js 
(index):59 GET http://192.168.43.172:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js 
(index):59 GET http://192.168.43.172:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js 
(index):60 GET http://192.168.43.172:8100/lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js 
ionic.bundle.js:13438 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:(…)